# Check For current owner's Role before updating new owner

Tags: visual-workflow, leads, ownership

I have a flow that assigns Lead owner to the current user. 
I just want to add a check before assigning owner  , The check should be like 
Check if the current owner has a particular role. Only than assign the lead to current user [image: flow]  .

Comment: it can be easily done with workflow rule, Is there any specific reason using flows?

Comment: Yes Because I am assigning this flow to a button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be easily done with Process Builder or a Workflow Rule. But since your question is how to do it with Visual Flow, then these are the steps you can take:

1. Use a **Fast Lookup** element to store the Lead's fields (including OwnerId) in an **sObject variable** (I'll name mine "varLead").
   [image]
2. **Note:** In the Fast Lookup, don't forget to **set the OwnerId field** in the section labeled **"Specify which of the record's fields to save in the variable"**.
   [image]
3. Create a new **Formula** to store the Lead Owner's Role Name using the cross-object field reference dot notation: **{!varLead.Owner.Role.DeveloperName}** (Make sure to use your Lead variable's name, mine is "varLead").
   [image]
4. Add a **Decision** element to check the **value of the new Formula** to make sure it is the correct Role. (Make sure to use the Role's Developer Name, aka Role Name, and not the Label).
   [image]
5. Connect the **Decision** element to your Record Update element using the **valid path**.
   [image]